# comm2sci function not working R taxize package

Tags: r, ropensci

I'm tryin to convert some common names to scientific names using `taxize`, but the functions are returning errors.

From the help page:

```
library(taxize)
comm2sci(commnames='black bear')
# Error: could not find function "comm2sci"
```

In addition, the `sci2comm` isn't working:

```
sci2comm(scinames='Helianthus annuus')
# Error: could not find function "sci2comm"
```

Ay reason they arent working? Any other way of getting scientific names in R?

Comment: Which version of taxize do you have?

Comment: Works fine for me on `taxize_0.2.6`. You can update your version with `devtools::install_github("ropensci/taxize")`

Comment: I thought I might be using an old version, so I ran `install.packages('taxize')`. I'll try `install_github`

Comment: @luciano I just tried with the version on CRAN `0.2.2`, and your examples worked fine for me. Though the default for `sci2comm` for the `db` param doesn't give any data, try `sci2comm(scinames='Helianthus annuus', db='itis')`

Comment: If I run `devtools::install_github("ropensci/taxize")` I get this error: `Installing github repo(s) ropensci/taxize/master from hadley
Downloading ropensci/taxize.zip from https://github.com/hadley/ropensci/taxize/archive/master.zip
Error: client error: (404) Not Found`

Comment: Your devtools is also out of date. Run this instead: `devtools::install_github("taxize", "ropensci")`

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is because the GitHub account name is not specified correctly and it is trying to download from Hadley's account (the default settings)

Comment: Thanks working now. What a useful tool!